# Is it possible to add Google Trusted Stores Order div dynamically?

Tags: jquery, google-trusted-stores

As the title of the question states, Is it possible to add Google Trusted Stores Order div dynamically with jQuery?

[image: GTS-Order]

The reason why I am appending this div with jQuery is I have required information in a JSON object and I do not have access to the source code of the page I am working on. All I can add some javascript/jquery functions to the html template page.

Comment: Yes, define the Google Store code as separate page, call that page with AJAX, and insert its code in the HTML source.

Comment: My only concern is will Google read dynamically added div/data? because what we append with jQuery does not show up in browser source view.

Comment: After the AJAX call is complete, on success add call to invoke Google Stroe